# Como capturar parâmetros do objeto que chamou um evento em Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Eu tenho 3 botões, dois com o mesmo nome e um com nome diferente e cada um com suas propriedades, eu gostaria de saber como capturar o texto de cada botão em uma mesma definição. Obvio, eu quero capturar a propriedade do botão que chamou o evento.

Por exemplo, na minha interface gráfica, aparece esses três botões:

Fatos
boatos
Supertição?

Quando eu clicar no botão **"Fatos"**, eu quero capturar o parâmetro Text desse botão, ou seja, o Fatos. Se eu clicar no **"boatos"** que compartilha o mesmo nome do botão **"Fatos"**, eu quero capturar o boatos. Tem como eu fazer isso com o Tkinter?

Meu código:

```
try:
    from tkinter import *
except:
    from Tkinter import *

tela = Tk()

def clicar():
   # Como exibir o texto do botão clicado?
   print(btn["text"])

btn = Button(tela,text="Fatos",font=("",20),bg="black",fg="white",command=clicar)
btn.grid(row=1,column=1)

btn = Button(tela,text="boatos",font=("",20),bg="black",fg="white",command=clicar)
btn.grid(row=2,column=1)

btn2 = Button(tela,text="Supertição?",font=("",20),bg="black",fg="white",command=clicar)
btn2.grid(row=3,column=1)

tela.mainloop()
```

Paleta de cores com a solução do **jsbueno**, Muito obrigado!:

```
try:
    from tkinter import *
except:
    from Tkinter import *

# Instância
tela = Tk()

# Lista de cores que vão aparecer na paleta
cores = ["#1bbc9b","#2ecd71","#3598db","#9b58b5","#5c6d7d","#16a086","#27ae61","#2a80b9","#8f44ad","#2d3e50","#f1c40f","#e77e23","#e84c3d","#ecf0f1","#95a5a5","#f39c11","#d55401","#c1392b","#bec3c7","#7e8c8d"]

# Definição que vai apenas exibir a cor escolhida.
def clicar(btn):
   print(btn["bg"])

linha = 1
# Variável que vai andar pela lista
quantidade = 0
while linha <=4:
    coluna = 1
    while coluna<=4:
        # Atualiza dados da cor
        cor_analise = cores[quantidade]

        # Cria um botão
        btn = Button(tela,font=(" ",12),bg=cor_analise,fg="white",activebackground=cor_analise,highlightbackground="white",highlightthickness=1,height=1,width=3)
        btn["command"] = lambda btn=btn: clicar(btn)
        btn.grid(row=linha,column=coluna)

        # Atualiza os andantes 
        coluna=coluna+1
        quantidade = quantidade+1
    linha = linha+1

tela.mainloop()
```

Comment: Por quê você precisa criar os dois primeiro botões com a mesma variável `btn`? Não pode criar uma variável para cada botão? Da maneira que está fazendo a variável que cria o botão "Fatos" é sobrescrita quando é criado o botão "boatos" .

Comment: Eu queria otimizar a criação de uma tabela de cores com aproximadamente 200 cores, são mais de 400 linhas para isso e milhares de parâmetros a se passar(Se eu lembrar de algum detalhe, tenho que mudar nas 200 linhas.) Usando loops com x e y eu crio toda a "tabela" com 30 linhas. No caso, cada "botão" atribui sua cor e seu texto de acordo com uma lista com todas as 200 cores. E no programa que eu estou fazendo, vai acontecer basante isso. Se eu conseguir capturar o parâmetro de um botão especifico, meu código sera reduzido em mais de 95%.

Comment: Eu atualizei minha pergunta usando uma versão beta da paleta, executa ela ai no Python3, a otimização é fantástica.

Comment: Esse código está mal feito ok, foi apenas um teste mesmo, a versão oficial da paleta ainda está no alfa e o código foi otimizado pelo menos 3 vezes mais do que esse de cima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma chamada de resposta ao "command" do tkinter não traz nenhuma informação do que foi clicado - a função é chamada sem nenhum parâmetro, e portanto, não tem nenhuma informação sobre como ou por quê foi chamada.

A única forma de ter ações diferentes para cada função é realmente ter funções distintas para cada controle.

**A boa notícia** é que essa função diferente não precisa ser declarada no programa, com `def`, e linhas de código: ela pode ser qualquer objeto chamável, que acrescenta informações sobre o botão ou controle onde aconteceu o evento, e então chama uma função principal, mas passando parâmetros a mais.

Uma forma de criar essas funções distintas para cada botão é com o uso da palavra chave `lambda`, que permite criar funções como parte de uma expressão (e assim você não precisa de 3 ou 4 linhas a mais pra cada botão).

Um outro detalhe se você quiser que a função que vai tratar o evento receba o próprio botão como parâmetro, a funçãozinha auxiliar não pode ser criada junto com aquele botão: ela precisa da referência ao objeto, então tem que ser atribuida depois que ele já existe.

O código fica algo assim:

```
def clicar(btn):
   # Como exibir o texto do botão clicado?
   print(btn["text"])

btn = Button(tela,text="Fatos",font=("",20),bg="black",fg="white")
btn["command"] = lambda btn=btn: clicar(btn)
btn.grid(row=1,column=1)

btn = Button(tela,text="boatos",font=("",20),bg="black",fg="white",command=clicar)
btn["command"] = lambda btn=btn: clicar(btn)
btn.grid(row=2,column=1)
```

Tem só mais um truque usado aí - é que ao criar as funções `lambda` com
o parâmetro default, o valor que a variável `btn` tem *no momento* em que o lambda é criado (ou seja, quando a linha é executada), é guardado como parte do próprio lambda. Isso é muito importante - por que se a função lambda simplesmente usasse a variável `btn` que existe "do lado de fora", no código que está criando os botões, o conteúdo de btn usado seria o do momento em que o botão fosse clicado: ou seja, não importa qual botão fosse clicado, o último botão criado é que seria passado como parâmetro.

Quanto a re-utilizar nomes de variáveis para criar vários controles, seja num laço, seja na criação explícita - isso de fato não tem problema algum, e é uma prática comum em código que cria interfaces gráficas.

Por outro lado, uma cisa pra prestar atenção é a identação do código: procure usar ma identação fixa de 4 espaços em cada bloco - vai ver que o código fica bem mais legível e com menos cara de bagunçado.  Usar uma identação variável, baseada na linha que abre o bloco não é u erro de sintaxe, mas não é a recomendação de *nenhum* guia de estilo de Python, e torna o código desagradável para conferência e leitura - inclusive para quem vai responder a perguntas sobre o mesmo.

Comment: Cara, resolveu meu problema perfeitamente, muito obrigado mesmo! Vou incorporar a nova versão da minha paleta de cores na pergunta. Show de bola!